# ActiveAdmin Autocomplete dropdown select not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, activeadmin

I am using activeadmin 0.4.4 along with rails3-jquery-autocomplete 1.0.15.

I was able to add autocomplete to a field.The dropdown shows perfectly as required.

However I am not able to select a value from the dropdown. (If I manually write the value in the text field it works fine). I get this error in the browser console and I am unable to figure out on how to proceed with this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
t.railsAutocomplete.fn.extend.init.t.autocomplete.select  -- active_adimn.js line 13982
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

Just installing [activeadmin_addons gem](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons#select2) you can convert select controls into [select2 controls](https://select2.github.io/examples.html). Use active admin's DSL as normal:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Detalles' do
    f.input :brand
    # more inputs...
  end
end
```

to get this:

[image]

If you want the normal select control, add `default-select` class like this:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Detalles' do
    f.input :brand, input_html: { class: 'default-select' }
    # more inputs...
  end
end
```

to get this:

[image]